# How to convert a set of strings to a list which is represented like [[string1,string2]] in python?

Tags: python

I have multiple strings that are always generated with a for-loop from Beautiful soup.

The structure of the html is:

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6" id="general-vessel-info">
    <section class="promo-box vessel-type-unknown border-radius-0 border-0 padding-0">
        <div class="padding-t-10 padding-l-30 padding-r-30" style="padding-bottom:8px;">
            <ul class="list-unstyled margin-0">
                <li><span><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i> Latest Event</span> <span class="font-daxmedium padding-l-10" id="general-vessel-event">New ETA: 2017-12-19 10:00 UTC<a class="margin-l-10 tooltip-bs hidden-md tab-switch" data-original-title="Show all Events" href="#event-log" title=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> more</a></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-t-10 padding-l-30 padding-b-10 padding-r-30" style="background-color:#F8F6F4;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled margin-0">
                        <li><span>Type</span> <span class="font-daxmedium" style="white-space:nowrap;">Tug <img alt="FleetMon Tug Icon" class="vessel-type tooltip-bs" data-original-title="Tug" src="//static.fleetmon.com/static/images/svg/types/unknown.svg" title=""></span></li>
                        <li><span>Flag</span> <span class="font-daxmedium"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">France <img alt="Flag of France" class="vessel-flag tooltip-bs" data-original-title="Flag of France" src="//static.fleetmon.com/static/images/svg/flags/fr.svg" title=""></span></span></li>
                        <li><span><abbr class="tooltip-bs" data-original-title="The unique ship identification number assigned by the International Maritime Organization" title="">IMO</abbr></span> <span class="font-daxmedium">9217474</span></li>
                        <li><span>MMSI</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">228058000</span></li>
                        <li><span>Callsign</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">FOUL</span></li>
                        <li><span>Year Built</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">–––</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled margin-0 laksbfdabfg">
                        <li><span>Length</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">30 m</span></li>
                        <li><span>Width</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">10 m</span></li>
                        <li><span>Draught <abbr class="font-size-11 tooltip-bs" data-original-title="Average Draught" style="color:#898E89;" title="">Avg</abbr></span> <span class="font-daxmedium">4.1 m / <span class="tooltip-bs" data-original-title="Minimum Draught: 0.1 m&lt;br&gt;Maximum Draught: 6.4 m" style="cursor:default;" title="">...</span></span></li>
                        <li><span>Speed <abbr class="font-size-11 tooltip-bs" data-original-title="Average &amp; Maximum Speed" style="color:#898E89;" title="">Avg/Max</abbr></span> <span class="font-daxmedium">7.5 kn / 7.3 kn</span></li>
                        <li><span>Deadweight</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">385 tons</span></li>
                        <li><span>Gross Tonnage</span> <span class="font-daxmedium">456 tons</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="text-center bg-color-FFFFFF" id="general-vessel-info-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default tab-switch" href="#datasheet"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Full Vessel Datasheet</a> <a class="btn btn-fm green margin-0 hidden-sm hidden-xs tab-switch" href="#datasheet" id="js-update-datasheet"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Update Datasheet</a>
        </footer>
    </section>
</div>
```

The expression is:

```
for ids in blockinfo.find_all('ul'):
    for li in ids.find_all('li'):
         print li.text.strip()
```

The strings are output as follows:

```
string1 
string2 
string3 
string4 
string5 
string6
```

I need to create a list like this:

```
[[string1,string2],[string3,string4][string5,string6]]
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Presumably those strings are grouped into `<ul><li><li></ul>` groups then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes the structure is like this

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you edited your question to contain the structure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't need to concatenate the strings together. The from the code below produces this output: [[string1+string2,string3+string4,string5+string6]]

Comment: No, it does not. If you could perhaps provide some sample HTML structure it'll be easier to figure out where you may be is-applying the code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the final output must be like this:
[[IMO,9217474],[Type,Tug]] and so on.
thanks

Comment: And my code does *exactly that*. For your sample input, it produces `[['Latest Event New ETA: 2017-12-19 10:00 UTC more'], ['Type Tug', 'Flag France', 'IMO 9217474', 'MMSI 228058000', 'Callsign FOUL', 'Year Built –––'], ['Length 30 m', 'Width 10 m', 'Draught Avg 4.1 m / ...', 'Speed Avg/Max 7.5 kn / 7.3 kn', 'Deadweight 385 tons', 'Gross Tonnage 456 tons']]`, which looks exactly right to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the output is correct. But i need to export just the values in a database. I was trying to use the first string as key in the list to identify each component uniquely. What can you suggest as option for this. Thanks

Comment: Ah, but that's a separate issue from your original question, that's a new issue. :-) You need to parse each `<li>` element, get the `<span>` elements and if there are two, put those as key and value into a dictionary. You could use my first example, make `elements = {}` a dictionary, then use `spans = ids.select('li span')` and `if len(spans) == 2:` and `key, value = (s.text.strip() for s in spans)` and `elements[key] = value` to get each two spans into a key-value pair in a dictionary, one dict per `ul`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question to post, this is not something solvable in comments.

Comment: Please don't. I've rolled back the edit. Questions are here for future visitors too, and you already received an answer to the problem stated. You now have a new problem, please use a new post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the help above, I finally manage to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to group the strings *per `<ul>` element*, then append them to a list you create inside the loop over each `<ul>` element, and then append that list to a result list each time you completed the loop over the contained `<li>` elements:

```
results = []
for ids in blockinfo.find_all('ul'):
    elements = []
    for li in ids.find_all('li'):
         elements.append(li.text.strip())
    results.append(elements)
```

You can use a list comprehension for that inner loop too:

```
results = []
for ids in blockinfo.find_all('ul'):
    results.append([
        li.text.strip() for li in ids.find_all('li')])
```

Converting the outer loop to a list comprehension also works:

```
results = [
    [li.text.strip() for li in ids.find_all('li')]
    for ids in blockinfo.find_all('ul')]
```

All three variants produce the same output; pick whichever you are most comfortable with maintaining in the long run. List comprehensions are a little faster than the `var = []; for ... in ...: var.append(...)` looping pattern.

Demo of the latter, using some mock input:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> blockinfo = BeautifulSoup('''
... <ul><li>string1</li><li>string2</li></ul>
... <ul><li>string3</li><li>string4</li></ul>
... <ul><li>string5</li><li>string6</li></ul>
... ''', 'lxml')
>>> [
...     [li.text.strip() for li in ids.find_all('li')]
...     for ids in blockinfo.find_all('ul')]
[['string1', 'string2'], ['string3', 'string4'], ['string5', 'string6']]
```

For your provided sample HTML, the above produces:

```
[['Latest Event New ETA: 2017-12-19 10:00 UTC more'],
 ['Type Tug',
  'Flag France',
  'IMO 9217474',
  'MMSI 228058000',
  'Callsign FOUL',
  'Year Built –––'],
 ['Length 30 m',
  'Width 10 m',
  'Draught Avg 4.1 m / ...',
  'Speed Avg/Max 7.5 kn / 7.3 kn',
  'Deadweight 385 tons',
  'Gross Tonnage 456 tons']]
```